# The next element can be obtained using Predict or SequencePredict?

Tags: integer-sequence

I want to estimate the next number with the data of the sequence listed as elements 0 and 1.

For example,

when `data = {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1}`

(actually, the data length is about 800)

Can the next element be obtained as a probability value using `Predict` or `SequencePredict`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with:

```
FindSequenceFunction@data
```

For example:

```
FindSequenceFunction[data] /@ Range[30]
```

> {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}

And for estimating just the next number:

```
FindSequenceFunction[data]@(Length[data] + 1)
```

> 0

While if you want the probabilities:

```
sp = SequencePredict[{#} & /@ data];
sp[{0}, "Probabilities"]
sp[{1}, "Probabilities"]
```

> <|0 -> 0.575472, 1 -> 0.424528|>
>   <|0 -> 0.575472, 1 -> 0.424528|>

And you can play with all the options of SequencePredict you can find in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Your consultation has been a great help. ^^

Comment: You are welcome :)